# MeteorJS Rendering With Data

Tags: templates, meteor, rendering

Hi Everybody i'm trying to rerender a template on MeteorJS, I'm using UI.renderWithData.
The code below is as far as i got, the problem is that wen I RERENDER the template with this UI.renderWithData(Template.numbers, {numbers : [11,12,13,14,15]}) it does not change the numbers value the numbers value stay as ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) they wer at the beginning.
What am I missing ?

```
Template.numbers.helpers({
            numbers: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        }); 

Template.numbers.events({
    "click #Generate" : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        instance = UI.renderWithData(Template.numbers, {numbers : [11,12,13,14,15]})

        UI.insert(instance, $('#numbers')[0]);
    }
})
```

I came to this regarding this tutorial : 
http://empire5.com/development/meteor-rendering-a-handlebars-template-with-dynamically-loaded-data/

Answer (score 1):

Helpers you define for the template take precedence over its data context. Therefore, when you define `numbers` as a helper for the template, the value given to this template as a context is ignored.

Helpers are not "defaults".

Comment: I actually have a function that generates the array of numbers the problem is when i re render the template it does not take other numbers from the function my real template helper looks like this :     Template.tiketa.helpers({ numbers: Tiketa() }); where the Tiketa() function generates a random array.

Comment: Maybe i did not understand you well as I'm a new programmer. If you can explain to me more simply and if you can suggest another way to what i'm wanting to do.
P.S All this idea cam to me from this post http://empire5.com/development/meteor-rendering-a-handlebars-template-with-dynamically-loaded-data/

Comment: @user1898399 When you give `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` they overwrite the ones you give with `[11,12,13,14,15]` because `.helpers` have a higher priority, they take precedence over the data context (the one taken with `UI.renderWithData`. So even when you use Tiketa() this would happen. Have you considered using `Session` (http://docs.meteor.com/#session) to pass your numbers instead? There is an example in the docs on how to use it under the .get section